# Ways to save data frame of tensors into a file for easy loading and access?

Tags: dataframe, torch

I have a dataframe with 2600 rows, and for each row there are torch tensors of shape `(192,)`.

[image]

How can I save this dataframe into a file so when I load it back again I could still use a "dictionary-like" access to it's contents?

Saving to_csv() converts the tensor into a string causing a mess where I need to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, using `pandas.to_pickle()` function retains the dataframe format and I can still access the data conveniently after loading it back.